# ¿Ocultar y mostrar contenido al oprimir botones?

Tags: javascript, html5

quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar con el siguiente problema que tengo, tengo 2 botones los cuales al oprimirlos muestran información diferente, pero quiero que si no se oprime ninguno estén ocultos y al oprimir uno u otro se muestre la información, y la otra se oculte, les dejo el código que estoy utilizando, si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería.

```
<button id="cambia" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprobar" type="button" class="btn btn-success bSi"></button>
<button id="cambiaN" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Negar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger bNo"></button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cambia").click(function(){
$("#textoAprobado").toggle(1000);
});
});
</script>


<div id="textoAprobado" class="col-md-6 alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<center>
<i class="fas fa-check-circle votos"></i><hr>¡Has votado a favor de este apoyo!
</center>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cambiaN").click(function(){
$("#textoAprobadoN").toggle(1000);
});
});
</script>


<div id="textoAprobadoN" class="col-md-6 alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<center>
<i class="fas fa-check-circle votos"></i><hr>¡Has votado en contra de este apoyo!
</center>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Hola :), puedes especificar qué version que JQuery y Bootstrap estás utilizando? ¿Deseas usar el toogle de Bootstrap o el de JQuery? Si deseas el de bootstrap, entonces no debes invocar el toogle de JQuery. Si deseas el de JQuery, entonces el atributo data-toggle sobra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero tienes que ocultar los DIVs (ambos) que tienen el texto. Ya después dependiendo que elijan, muestras uno y ocultas el otro.

Te dejo el JS con comentarios

PD. Se puede simplificar más el código, sin embargo te enredarás más. Échate un clavado a cómo funciona Bootstrap, por el momento el problema está resuelto.
[Tutorial Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Saludos

```js
//Lo mismo que document.ready
$(function(){
  
  //Trigger del texto a favor
  $(document).on('click','#cambia',function(){
    //Se muestra que votaste a favor
    $('#textoAprobado').show('fast');
    //Se oculta que votaste en contra
    $('#textoAprobadoN').hide('fast');
  });
  
  //Trgger del texto en contra
  $(document).on('click','#cambiaN',function(){
    //Se oculta que votaste a favor
    $('#textoAprobado').hide('fast');
    //Se muestra que votaste en contra
    $('#textoAprobadoN').show('fast');
  });

});
```

```css
#textoAprobado, #textoAprobadoN{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cambia" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Aprobar" type="button" class="btn btn-success bSi">Texto aprobado</button>
<button id="cambiaN" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Negar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger bNo">Texto aprobado N</button>


<div id="textoAprobado" class="col-md-6 alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<center>
<i class="fas fa-check-circle votos"></i><hr>¡Has votado a favor de este apoyo!
</center>
</div>


<div id="textoAprobadoN" class="col-md-6 alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<center>
<i class="fas fa-check-circle votos"></i><hr>¡Has votado en contra de este apoyo!
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Alberto, la respuesta es perfecta :), ¿puedo sugerirte corregir un error de ortografía?

Comment: Claro, dime dónde corrijo.

Comment: Échate en lugar de Héchate :)

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob ¡Me has salvado, justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias, saludos!